# Is this brick knee wall tied in to the main wall?

Tags: brick, structural, masonry, stone, demolition

We would like to remove the L-shaped brick "knee wall" in the picture on the left. The picture on the right shows the seam between the knee wall and the main wall of the house. Is the knee wall likely tied into the house and the removal would require an elaborate repair or is it "free standing"? Is there a minimally invasive way of finding out?
[image]

Comment: only you can find out for sure ... plan for it to be tied to the other wall

Comment: A close up of the inside corner will be useful. The paint on the wall on the right looks like it has more coats than the wall you want to remove, suggesting it was built later.. Unless there is a better view of the actual corner seing how the vertical joints are placed, I cannot be 100% sure If all the vertical joints in the corner are on the wall you want to remove, then it was added after. If the vertical joints are alternating from one wall face to the other it was tied in.